# pst-3dplot and drawing cylinders

Tags: pstricks, technical-drawing, pst-3dplot

I am drawing a cylinder with `\psCylinder` from [`pst-3dplot`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/pst-3dplot), as shown here in a MWE from the manual:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pst-3dplot}

\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}(-3,-2)(3,7)
\psset{Beta=10}
\pstThreeDCoor[zMax=7]
\psCylinder[increment=5]{2}{5}
\end{pspicture}


\end{document}
```

The `z`-axis points vertically - how can I make it horizontal?

Comment: Don't you just want the cylinder to lay horizontal rather than have the z-axis be horizontal?

Comment: The cylinder axis should be aligned with `z`

Comment: I don't know exactly what you're after. You *can* rotate the axis as well as the cylinder (independently). See p 19 (section **4 Rotation**) of the [`pst-plot3d`](http://ctan.org/pkg/pst-plot3d) [documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pstricks/contrib/pst-3dplot/doc/pst-3dplot-doc.pdf).

Comment: @Werner Using `RotZ=0` doesn't make the z-axis horizontal, it always points vertically (either up or down)

Comment: Using `\pstThreeDCoor[RotSequence=quaternion,RotSet=set,RotAngle=90,xRotVec=1,yRotVec=0,zRotVec=0,zMax=7]` rotates the z-axis through 90 degrees around the x-axis.

Answer (score 3):

Do you want something like this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pst-3dplot}
\begin{document}

\psset{Alpha=0,Beta=90}
\begin{pspicture}(-3,-2)(3,7)
\pstThreeDCoor[zMax=7]
\psCylinder[RotX=90,RotY=45,increment=5]{2}{5}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]